# Copy policy.xml to meta-inf of ear file while creating ear file

Tags: ant, build

can anyone let me know how to copy policy.xml and some xml file to META-INF of the EAR file while creating EAR file using ANT script.

sample

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the [task descriptio](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html)n they mention...

The nested metainf element specifies a FileSet. All files included in this fileset will end up in the META-INF directory of the ear file. If this fileset includes a file named MANIFEST.MF, the file is ignored and you will get a warning.

Example:

```
<ear destfile="${build.dir}/myapp.ear" appxml="${src.dir}/metadata/application.xml">
  <metainf dir="${xml.dir}" includes="*.xsd,*.xml"/>
</ear>
```